# ListView control: prevent select all via Ctrl+A

Tags: wpf, xaml

I need to prevent the user from selecting all items in a ListView control using Ctrl+A. I added an event handler for KeyDown to the ListView but this does not help as it appears that the items are selected before my KeyDown event handler is called.

EDIT 1: The reason for preventing this is that there is a requirement to limit how many items can be interacted with at once and it was thought that allowing Ctrl+A to select all may imply that the user can perform actions on all items.

EDIT 2: It appears that the ListView control handles Ctrl+A by default - can this be prevented?

Comment: It might help if you explain what you're trying to achieve. Why don't you just change the `SelectionMode` to `Single` or `None`?

Comment: @PaoloMoretti I have edited my question. I would like to allow the user to select any number of items but not via Ctrl+A.

Comment: I see, perhaps rather than disabling Ctrl+A you should try to set a maximum number of selected items.

Comment: it will be (SelectionMode="Single") in default  in listbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not try to block all possible methods to select all documents. I would recommend a single solution; i.e. an eventHandler when an item gets selected. In the handler you should cancel in case the selection would exceed the allowed number of items.